# WCF: Why to use System.ServiceModel.Channels.Message class?

Tags: wcf, message

I have a general question. Why sometimes should we use System.ServiceModel.Channels.Message class instead of some concrete class when we create WCF service?

For example:

1) We can use the following:

```
public Person GetPersonById(int id)
{
    Person person = Employees.CreateEmployees().First(e => e.Id == id);
    return person;
}
```

2) But we can use the following as well:

```
public Message GetPersonById(Message id)
{
    string firstName = Employees.CreateEmployees().First(e => e.Id == id.GetBody<int>()).FirstName;
    Message response = Message.CreateMessage(id.Version, ReplyAction, firstName);
    return response;
}
```

What's the difference? Will I have the same result in both cases?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Short answer - it is higher level of abstraction.
For exampe if your service must undersend expandable list of message types without actualy changing its contract or imagine a load balancing WCF proxy.

Also in message processing pipeline it is impossible to create generic mechanisms for handling messages without this kind of abstraction.

Comment: Not my question, but interested in the answer....could you give some code snippet examples or more explanation?

Comment: Thank you Alexey. Could you tell me, please, what's the difference between 2 code snippets I've posted? Why to use 1) and don't use 2) and vice versa?

Comment: if you need some low level work with message - go to message, else - use strong typed models. As a good example for you both: Open Microsoft.IdentityModel.SecurityTokenService.SecurityTokenService class from WIF in reflector. It is nice example of low level work with messages.